# UITableView not displaying correctly on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator, xcode8

On the iPhone, the tableview looks fine, but in the iPad (simulator ios10), this is how it's shown:

Check image here: http://welove.pt/img/ipadtrouble.png

Any idea why its displaying differently on iPhone/iPad?
Also, what's with that white corner by the search icon? why isn't it black?

ViewDidLoad:

```
_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.dataSource = self;
_tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:58/255.0 green:58/255.0 blue:58/255.0 alpha:1.0];
_tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0);
_tableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
[self.view addSubview:_tableView];
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
        selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(54/255.0) green:(54/255.0) blue:(54/255.0) alpha:1];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(28/255.0) green:(28/255.0) blue:(28/255.0) alpha:1];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.imageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"defineLocation.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        UILabel *ttitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(46, 12, 320, 20)];
        ttitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
        ttitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(115/255.0) green:(229/255.0) blue:(69/255.0) alpha:1.0];
        [ttitle setText:NSLocalizedString(@"current_location", nil)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:ttitle];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[_recentSearchData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"recentTitle"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that `[cell.contentView addSubview:ttitle]` is not recommended because cells are reused. Instead why not using a custom cell?

Comment: That may solve the UILabel position on the cell. But where i'm really lost is the tableview left inset on the iPad :(

Comment: this is bad ui. you keep adding a view when you scroll to the first section. create a uitableviewcell subclass and do the UI init there. in the cell for row just dequeue the registered cell and update the label or whatever.

Comment: Thank you Larme and Joshua, subclassing solved the alignment issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclassing the UITableViewCell solved the alignment issues.

Regarding that white arrow when the view is popping over on the iPad, i managed to change it's color with:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(23/255.0) green:(23/255.0) blue:(23/255.0) alpha:1.0];
}
```

this viewWillAppear belongs to the UITableViewController that is shown in the popover.

Thanks for your suggestions